# Roblox API Login endpoint Captcha Provider

Tags: captcha, roblox, provider

I am trying to log in through the API of roblox and the problem is that I use reCaptcha and there's a field in body request that's called "captchaProvider", I've tried to something like GOOGLE, RECATPCHA_V2 and that's not working for me. I've seen people using Arkose Labs captcha but on their website its only something like request demo...

[image: Screenshot of postman request]

https://auth.roblox.com/docs#!/Authentication/post_v2_login

That's the API docs link, If someone know the way how to use other provider than Arkose labs for captcha I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `funcaptcha` and in `provides` you should write:

```
PROVIDER_ARKOS_LABS
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).